# Run rake task from outside RAILS_ROOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, task

My RAILS_ROOT is /usr/local/www/application/

If I run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" from within the RAILS_ROOT it works fine.

However I can't seem to find a way to run the same command from outside the RAILS_ROOT.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
rake -f $RAILS_ROOT/Rakefile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
# Assuming you set the environment variable. 
# Else, just replace $RAILS_ROOT by actual value
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to re-think your question. When running `rake` without specifying a rakefile, it's going to search in the current directory for said rakefile. In a directory besides RAILS_ROOT, it's going to find no rakefile or the wrong Rakefile

`rake -rakefile /usr/local/www/application/Rakefile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` might work (assuming [the rake user guide](http://docs.rubyrake.org/user_guide/chapter02.html) is correct), though you may have to be in the directory for poorly designed plugins/library modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cd /user/local/www/application && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```